# Angular ng-show handling undefined variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I've two directives which display based on a variable being configured.

This visually worked but during acceptance tests I found a problem. I attempted to assert that if the `<settingElement>` hasn't been clicked (configuring the `var selected`), neither directive is displayed. The test passed for `<directiveA>` but failed for `<directiveB>` leaving me a little confused.

An example of the code is below:

```
<settingElement ng-click="selected = trueOrFalse()"></settingElement>

<directiveA ng-show="selected"></directiveA>
<directiveB ng-show="!selected"></directiveB>
```

Comment: Can you show us all of your directive code. Or even better give us a plunker?

Comment: I think it's because when `settingElement` is not clicked `selected = undefined` and inside `directiveB` ng-show expression receive true because in JavaScript `!undefined = true`

Comment: Thanks Grievoushead! You've help me find the answer, I'll post below

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear, clicking the `settingElement` does not guarantee a certain outcome so no assumptions on this can be made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! At least kinda, visually the code works so instead of testing for `isDisplayed` I simply asserted that the height and width are both 0... not ideal but works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way of doing this would be to define `selected` in a parent of both elements, such as:

```
<div ng-init="selected = false;">
    <settingElement ng-click="selected = true"></settingElement>

    <directiveA ng-show="selected"></directiveA>
    <directiveB ng-show="!selected"></directiveB>
</div>
```

Another "shorter workaround" would be

```
<settingElement ng-click="selected = true"></settingElement>

<directiveA ng-show="!!selected"></directiveA>
<directiveB ng-show="!selected"></directiveB>
```

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear, clicking the `settingElement` does not guarantee a certain outcome so no assumptions on this can be made

Comment: Sounds like pretty bad design for me

Comment: Please do explain. The code itself works... nothing is visible initially and depending on the call a success or fail message is displayed. It's the test asserting `isDisplayed` which fails

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the expression triggering with undefined values

try with `ng-if ="selected" or ng-show="selected==true"`